# Bug in org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator with inheritance, @XmlAttribute and @XmlAnyAttribute?

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

The issues:

- Is there a but in MOXy's SchemaGenerator with inheritance, @XmlAttribute and @XmlAnyAttribute?
- If so, how can I assist in fixing it? And when would a fix be planned?

I have two classes:

1. One abstract class (AbstractKeyedItem) that may have an @XmlAttribute "key"
2. A concrete class (MyAnyAttr) that extends AbstractKeyedItem, has a @XmlAnyAttribute, and has an @XmlElement list of MyAnyAttr

The problem is that the default Oracle (Sun) XmlSchemaGenerator generates a valid XML Schema, but that the Eclipselink/MOXy SchemaGenerator doesn't seem to do so.

Eclipse reports on the invalid XSD:

```
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'myAnyAttr' is invalid. Element 'anyAttribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

xmllint reports:

```
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)))).
```

I think to have isolated the problem. I provide all (most) required resources.

XSD as generated by MOXy (xsd:anyAttribute is the offending element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="myAnyAttr">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="abstractKeyedItem">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="kid" type="myAnyAttr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="skip" namespace="##other"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="abstractKeyedItem" abstract="true">
      <xsd:sequence/>
      <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="my-any-attr-root" type="myAnyAttr"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

The XSD generated by Oracle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="my-any-attr-root" type="myAnyAttr"/>

  <xs:complexType name="myAnyAttr">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="abstractKeyedItem">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="kid" type="myAnyAttr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="abstractKeyedItem" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Abstract class:

```
package xml.anyattr;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public abstract class AbstractKeyedItem {

  @XmlAttribute
  public String key;

  public AbstractKeyedItem() {}
}
```

Concrete class:

```
package xml.anyattr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRootElement(name = "my-any-attr-root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyAnyAttr extends AbstractKeyedItem {

  @XmlAnyAttribute
  public Map<QName, String> attrMap = new HashMap<QName, String>();

  @XmlElement(name = "kid")
  public List<MyAnyAttr> myAnyAttrKids = new ArrayList<MyAnyAttr>();

  public MyAnyAttr() {}
}
```

Utilities used to generate files:

```
package xml.anyattr;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.PropertyException;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils;

public class MyAnyAttrUtils {

  private static class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

    @Override
    public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
      new Throwable().printStackTrace(System.out);
      File file = null;
      if (namespaceUri.equals("")) {
        file = XSD;
      } else {
        throw new IOException("Unsupported namespaceUri: " + namespaceUri);
      }
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
      result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
      return result;
    }
  }

  static File XSD = new File("target/test-classes/my-any-utils.xsd");

  private static void generateXsd() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    rm(XSD);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyAnyAttr.class);
    SchemaOutputResolver outputResolver = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
    jaxbContext.generateSchema(outputResolver);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(XSD);
    System.out.println("XSD:");
    IOUtils.copy(is, System.out);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      printSimple();
      generateXsd();
      System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  private static void printSimple() throws JAXBException, PropertyException {

    MyAnyAttr myAnyAttr = new MyAnyAttr();
    myAnyAttr.key = "parent";
    myAnyAttr.attrMap.put(new QName("oth", "dad"), "foo");

    MyAnyAttr kid = new MyAnyAttr();
    kid.key = "child";
    kid.attrMap.put(new QName("oth", "kid"), "bar");

    myAnyAttr.myAnyAttrKids.add(kid);

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyAnyAttr.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    System.out.println("XML:");
    marshaller.marshal(myAnyAttr, System.out);
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void rm(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.exists()) {
      if (!file.delete()) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to delete " + file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Stack trace of Oracle implementation:

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils$MySchemaOutputResolver.createOutput(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:25)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.FoolProofResolver.createOutput(FoolProofResolver.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.XmlSchemaGenerator.write(XmlSchemaGenerator.java:462)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.generateSchema(JAXBContextImpl.java:794)
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils.generateXsd(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:44)
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils.main(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:53)
```

Stack trace of MOXy implementation:

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils$MySchemaOutputResolver.createOutput(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.getSchemaForNamespace(SchemaGenerator.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.addSchemaComponents(SchemaGenerator.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.generateSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.generateSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Generator.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.generateSchema(JAXBContext.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.generateSchema(JAXBContext.java:353)
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils.generateXsd(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:44)
    at xml.anyattr.MyAnyAttrUtils.main(MyAnyAttrUtils.java:53)
```

Comment: Peeked into the [git code repository](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/moxy/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/src/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/SchemaGenerator.java). Looks like `addAnyAttributeToSchema(ComplexType)` and/or the calling don't take into account the possibility that the type is based on another type.

Comment: Why do you ask us here and not project developers on github?

Comment: I realized so after posting. Guess I was too absorbed in documenting the case that it didn't occur to me. Will do.